# Method in a Entity Partial Class don't appears on new instances

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a entity class Usuario and I want to create a partial class to add some methods in Usuario. I did:

```
public partial class Usuario
{
    public static List<string> CarregarPreferencias(){
        // Do it!
        return null;
    }
}
```

When I call Usuario in Context "Ctx.Usuario.CarregarPreferencias()" it appears, but when I create a instance of Usuario it not:

```
Usuario user = new Usuario();
user.CarregarPrefer..... // <<< my method don't appears
```

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[A static method doesn't appear on instances of the class.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Remove static from the method declaration if you want to call the method against instances of the class.